# Creating Anonymous suggestions box

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

How to create anonymous suggestions box for SharePoint 2013? I want to do using OOB. Please I need help.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

- Create a Survey list for suggestions (but this sets the CreatedBy field)
- Then use a Workflow **with elevated permissions** to copy the Item to another List (everything but the CreatedBy info)
- Let the workflow delete the Item in the Survey list

Comment: In the second list who will the items show as being CreatedBy? Will it not pull through the workflow initiator (and therefore the original survey respondent) ?